# Problems Installing MikTeX on Linux

Tags: errors, miktex

I am trying to install MiKTeX on Linux Mint following [this guide](http://miktex.org/howto/build-unx). Unfortunately, I get an error message after executing the command:

`cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"`

Here is the output:

> CMake Error at
>
> /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
>
> Could NOT find ImageMagick (missing: ImageMagick_mogrify_EXECUTABLE)
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>
> /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
>
> /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindImageMagick.cmake:268 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
>     CMakeLists.txt:562 (find_package)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>
> See also "/home/"user"/miktex-2.9-2016-06-27/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Could someone explain how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the `CMakeOutput.log` saying?

Comment: Well it says `Could NOT find ImageMagick (missing: ImageMagick_mogrify_EXECUTABLE)`: Do you have this package installed on your linux machine? If not, install it and try it again.

Comment: Why are you trying to do it? Why don't you use texlive?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I need the scrartcl.cls file for another class to work which serves as a template for a paper I have to write.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT yes, ImageMagick is installed.

Comment: @Exitus As Ulrike said "why even use miktex on Linux"? Which miktex tools do you need that TeX Live does not already provide, and then some. One advantage is that TeX Live installs everything by default. Miktex does not.

Comment: @UlrikeFischerThanks, installing the texlive-full  package solved my problem. I only had the base version installed previously.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the installation of full TeXLive solves the problem ... (see last comment of OP)

Answer (score 0):

## CMakeOutput.log

Because the file is so long, I thought it would be better to just take pictures, the formatting is better too.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]